# Split large S3 txt file line by line and upload each line as a document to another bucket AWS Lambda (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm at wits end trying to figure out how I should go about my situation. I'm fairly new in AWS and couldn't find something that fits my use-case yet.

So, I have a huge text file in one S3 location. I would like to split the file line by line and upload each line as a separate txt file to another S3 location in an AWS lambda (Python).

I tried to use boto3 streaming, etc. The Lambda is timing out because of the number of lines. Please suggest something.

Comment: What is your timeout setting on the Lambda function? You could run your code on an Amazon EC2 instance instead of using an AWS Lambda function. That way, you are not limited by a timeout. Is this a one-off activity, or something that will be required on a continuing basis? How many lines are in the file? I'd assume that most of the time is taken by the overhead of uploading so many files. What are you going to do with the individual files once they are created -- if you tell us about your actual end-goal, we might be able to suggest an alternate approach.